# Unity3D C# - Parse JSON that has an additional array around data

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, parsing

I'm stuck in a situation where my json (coming from a source I can't control) has a sort of "middle man" array that doesn't do anything.

If I modify the json I can get values out but as it is I'm stumped.

*stripped down json example*

```
"geopoly": {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        -74.7,
        40.72
      ],
      [
        -74.73,
        40.71
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

**Question**

How can I convert json similar to this into a c# object using the Unity `JsonUtility.FromJson`?

*current attempt: c# containers for parsing*

```
[Serializable]
public struct GeoPoly
{
    public string type;
    public List<FloatList> coordinates;
}

[Serializable]
public class MiddleManList : List<FloatList> {}

[Serializable]
public class FloatList : List<float> {}
```

I can see "type" correctly but "coordinates" is always `[0]: Count = 0` or null so I'm not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it this way

```
var data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(json);
```

add Root  and coordinates

```
[Serializable]
public class Root
{
  public Geopoly geopoly {get; set;}
}
[Serializable]
public struct GeoPoly
{
    public string type {get; set;}
    public List<List<List<float>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

and fix json by wrapping in {}

```
{
"geopoly": {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        -74.7,
        40.72
      ],
      [
        -74.73,
        40.71
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
}
```

if it is not workig still try to remove {get; set;}, some versions of unity serializer doesn't know how to serialize properties.

Comment: It seems that without `[Serializable]` with the "Root" class I get null data. Furthermore, with `{ get; set; }` after "geopoly" I get `null` for geopoly. Were you getting data when you ran it ?

Comment: @Jacksonkr I don't have unity to test.  it is just a hint for you how to change your classes. I am sorry, but I am not a free coder here and not going to do all coding for you. All you need  now is  to add [Serializable] and I hope you are qualified enough to do this. if it is not workig still try to remove {get; set;}, some versions of unity serializer doesn't know how to serialize properties.

Comment: No one here is a free coder so your kindness goes a long way. I've switched to `Newtonsift.Json` as my original code works in there, yours does too. Cheers.

Comment: @Jacksonkr I am really sorry, I didn't mean to insult you. Just before you was almost the same case with vb.net. I don't have vb.net compiler to test too and it was only one line of code.

Comment: @Serge `some versions of unity serializer doesn't know how to serialize properties` .. all of them ;) [Unity Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) is explicitly limited to fields. You can enforce it for properties adding `[field: SerializeField]` put in that use case here .. why not simply rather use fields instead ;) and also `Note: Unity does not support serialization of multilevel types (multidimensional arrays, jagged arrays, and nested container types).` ;)